# How do I determine what file calls a bash command at login?

Tags: macos, command-line, mac, bash, login

I'm a computer science student on Mac OSX El Capitan. My friend made it so that my computer runs `say 'heil hitler'` whenever I login to a new instance of Terminal. Needless to say, I need to get rid of it. For now, I have renamed /usr/bin/say to /usr/bin/0say to keep it from going off in public. I have checked ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc, ~/.login, /etc/bashrc. Are there other files automatically run at bash login?

Beyond that, how can I find out what config file is actually calling a given command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `set` command, man page [here](http://ss64.com/bash/set.html). Specifically:

- `set -x` to show commands after expansion, just before execution
- `set -v` to show commands as they are read in, before expansion

For example, insert `set -xv` at the top of your ~/.profile and you will see everything your terminal is doing after that line. You may want to capture that output (or copy-paste from Terminal into a text document) and do something like `grep -B 4 hitler` to give you an idea of where it is.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Doing set -xv showed me that there was a large number of empty lines being run between my ~/.bash_profile and the say 'heil hitler'. Turns out my friend had hidden it after a bunch of new lines in my ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 1):

Several investigation techniques come to mind:

- In addition to the shell init files you looked at, check `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `/etc/profile`.
- For the per-user init files, try disabling them by renaming; if removing one particular file keeps it from running `say`, then you know it's something in that file. You can also put a `return` command partway through an init file to see if the call to `say` is before or after that point.
- You can add `set -x` in an init file, and it'll make the shell print out commands as it executes them; makes tracing execution easy.
- Brute force search your home folder: `grep -r hitler ~`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already solved the problem but I would have also checked my Terminal shortcut. It could have been replaced with any number of script shortcuts, AppleScript being the most likely, to perform this prank.